# Creating baseline comparison data in shiny R - Duplicating inputted dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

The aim of this exercise is to allow users to compare two different models based on their inputs. To do this, I have created an action button that asks users to specify their base model, and a reset button that takes the dataset back to before the baseline was added. The "base" logical determines whether the user wishes to include the base or not.

Once the add baseline actionbutton is clicked, the current state of the data.frame is saved and grouping variable is renamed with "baseline" added before it (using paste). Users can select a different model which renders in comparison to this static base.

For some reason, I cannot get the observe event to change the dataset. The observe event creates the baseline dataset fine (tested with print() ), however, the if() function does not alter "data" and therefore stops the base added to the ggplot. The code is written like this for two reasons. 1)  by including the if() function after the observe event, any further changes to data only changes "data", it then gets added to the unchanged baseline data. 2) Also allows for the creation of the reset button which simply resets the data.frame to before the rbinding took place.

This small issue has infuriated me and I cannot see where I am going wrong. Cheers in advance for any help people can provide. There are simplier ways to do this (open to suggestions), however, the iris data is only an example of the function, and the actual version is more complex.

```
library("ggplot2")
if (interactive()) {

 ui <- fluidPage(
selectInput("rows", label = h3("Choose your species"), 
            choices = list("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
            ),
actionButton("base", "Create baseline"),
actionButton("reset", "Reset baseline"),
plotOutput(outputId = "plot")

            )     # close fluid page

 server <- function(input, output) {


output$plot <- renderPlot({      # create plot
  base <- "no"                   # create baseline indicator which we can change once the observeevent below is changed
  data <- iris

  data <- iris[which(data$Species == input$rows),]         # Get datasubset based on user input

  observeEvent(input$base, {                                                   # If base is Pressed, run code below:
    baseline <- data                                                           # Make Baseline Data by duplicating the users' specification
    baseline$Species <- paste("Baseline", 
                        data$Species, sep = "_")                                # Rename the grouping variable to add Baseline B4 it
    base <- "yes"                # Change our indicator of whether a baseline had been made to yes
  })                                        # Close observe Event

  observeEvent(input$reset, {    

    base <- "no"    # This is placed before the rbind so that if we want to reset it will stop the merging of the two dataframes before it happens.
  })



  if (base == "yes") {

    data <- rbind(data, baseline)       # Run once the observe event has changed baseline to yes.This is kept seperatel that way any subsequent changes to data will not effect 
                                        # the final data. This command will simple add the base onto the changed "data" before plotting
  }

  observeEvent(input$reset, {    

    base <- "no"
                             })


  ggplot(data, aes(x=Petal.Width, y = as.numeric(Sepal.Width), colour = Species)) +    # variable = each dataset selected, value = respective values for that model
    labs(x="Hypothetical X", y="Hypothetical X") +
    geom_line() 
})                                          # Close Render Plot
  }                                            # Close Serve Function
  shinyApp(ui, server)
                                 }
```

## EXAMPLE TWO WITH REACTIVE OBJECT

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library("tidyr")
library("dplyr")
library("data.table")

# Lets make a fake dataset called "Data". Has 4 variable options and     
the Ages each data point relates to. 
Ages <- 1:750
Variable1 <- rnorm(n=750, sd = 2, mean = 0)
Variable2 <- rnorm(n=750, sd = 1, mean = 2)
Variable3 <- rnorm(n=750, sd = 8, mean = 6)
Variable4 <- rnorm(n=750, sd = 3, mean = 3)

Data <- as.data.frame(cbind(Ages, Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, 
Variable4) )

### UI

ui <- fluidPage(
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "columns",                                                           
                 label = h4("Which Variables would you like in your  
model?"),                    # Input Checkbox                                      
                 choices =   c("Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", 
"Variable4")),

  plotOutput(outputId = "plot"),                                                        
  # Lets have our plot                                                                          
 actionButton("base", "Create baseline"),                                  
 # Baseline action
  actionButton("reset", "Reset baseline")        # Reset Action
 )  # Close UI



server <- function(input, output) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({             
validate(need(!is.null(input$columns),  'Please tick a box to show a 
plot.'))   # Place a please choose columns for null input

data <- gather(select(Data, "Ages", input$columns), variable, value, -
Ages) ## Just doing a little data manipulation to change from wide to 
long form. This allows for calculations down the track and easier 
plotting

# Now we can modify the data in some way, for example adding 1. Will     
eventually add lots of model modifications here. 

data$value <- data$value + 1                

rVals <- reactiveValues()            # Now we create the reactive 
values object
rVals[['data']] <- data              # Making a reactive values 
function. Place Data as "data". 

  observeEvent(input$base,{
  baseline <- data
  baseline$variable <- paste("Baseline", 
                                baseline$variable, sep = "_")                
  # Rename Variables to Baseline preamble
  rVals[['baseline']] <- baseline                                             
 # Put the new data into the reactive object under "baseline"
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset,{            # Reset button will wipe the 
data
  rVals[['baseline']] <- NULL
})

if(!is.null(rVals[['baseline']]))      # if a baseline has been . 
created, then 
{rVals[['final']] <- bind_rows(rVals[['data']], rVals[['baseline']])           
# Here we can simply bind the two datasets together if Baseline exists
} else {rVals[['final']] <- rVals[['data']]}                                   
# Otherwise we can use keep it as it is


## Make our Plot !

ggplot(rVals[['final']], aes(x=Ages, y = as.numeric(value), colour = 
variable)) +    # variable = each dataset selected, value = respective 
values for that model
  labs(x="Age", y="value") +
  geom_line() 

  })                              ## Close the render plot

}                                 ## Close the server                                            

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have observer inside reactive expression, i have seen this causing problems on number of occasions when i was correcting shiny code. Create reactive expression (your plot function) and observers only to specify which is the baseline value of species (character string) then feed this to filtering data inside the plot function:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("rows", label = h3("Choose your species"), 
              choices = list("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
  ),
  actionButton("base", "Create baseline"),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset baseline"),
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot")

)     # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output) {
  rVals = reactiveValues()
  rVals[['data']] = iris
  rVals[['baseline']] = NULL
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    # here we duplicate table to manipulate it before rendering
    # the reason for duplicate is that you dont want to affect your
    # base data as it may be used elsewhere
    # note that due to R's copy-on-write this may be expensive operation and 
    # have impact on app performance
    # in all cases using data.table package is recommended to mitigate 
    # some of the CoW implications
    render.data = rVals[['data']][rVals[['data']][['Species']] %in% c(rVals[['baseline']],input$rows),]

    # here manipulate render.data

    # and then continue with plot
    ggplot(data=render.data, 
           aes(x=Petal.Width, y = as.numeric(Sepal.Width), colour = Species,group=Species)
    ) +    
      labs(x="Hypothetical X", y="Hypothetical X") +
      geom_line() 
  })
  observeEvent(input$base,{
    rVals[['baseline']]=input$rows
  })
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    rVals[['baseline']]=NULL
  })

}                                            
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sweet thanks for your input, your solution works well to store the base data as baseline and add it using rVals object. Do you think there is a way to simply add the datasets together before plotting within renderPlot? This would allow me to modify the inputted values (e.g., run a function over the selected datasets) and store that as the base? i.e. have several steps of calculation between input$rows and the plot. Perhaps one line of code between rVals[['baseline']] = NULL      and 
  output$plot <- renderPlot({    Which joins the data together b4 the plot?

Comment: Thanks Peter for all your help on this topic, the reactive input would work well! Last question I had on this topic. If I was to disconnect the input from the dataset earlier on in the pipeline, how would your solution look? I have included a modified version of the same add using your solution and my aims. At the moment it only loops an error in the console. Thanks in advance for all your time and advice.

Comment: In Shiny functions reactive, observe, observeEvent,eventReactive and renderXYZ respond to inputs inside the function if they are present, the difference is when they are evaluated. There are some topics on shiny reactive environment to read to grasp more understanding. In my example the rVals[['baseline']] was auxiliary variable that either assumed null state or value from input$rows to help filtering main data, you should not assign table to it. I will have a look at your code later today and propose a solution

Comment: Thanks @PeterS ! The second half of the code in my example follows your advice using the reactiveObject. It appears to work until the compare actionbutton is pressed. When this happens, the figure becomes dull. This suggests that the rVal[[`Final`]] works until it becomes merged with the baseline and inputted data, then creates issues.